# Custom loss function for 2-player game with odds in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to code a custom loss function in the image below, in Keras for a 2 player game. So far I have achieved the below and the model compiles without error too, however not sure if the implementation is correct?

[image]

```
def custom_odds_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    odds1 = y_true[:, 1]
    odds2 = y_true[:, 2]
    y_true = y_true[:, 0]
    return -1 * K.mean(K.sum((odds1 * y_true - 1.) * K.maximum(odds1 * y_pred - 1., K.zeros_like(odds1)) + (odds2 * (y_true - 1.) - 1.) * K.maximum(odds2 * (1. - y_pred) - 1., K.zeros_like(odds2)), axis=1))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
    def odds_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        risultato1 = y_true[:, 0:1]
        risultato2 = y_true[:, 1:2]
        odds1 = y_true[:, 2:3]
        odds2 = y_true[:, 3:4]
        risultatoPred1=y_pred[:, 0:1]
        risultatoPred2=y_pred[:, 1:2]
        return K.mean((odds1*risultato1-1.)*K.relu(odds1*risultatoPred1-1.)+(odds2*risultato2-1.)*K.relu(odds2*risultatoPred2-1.))
```

Comment: A good answer should always include an explanation.

Comment: custom loss in keras get 2 parameters, then I've append odds in y_true vector.
risultato1 is 0 or 1, it is true resut, for example home team win in a game with no tie. Risultato2 is away result and is 0 or 1. odds1 and odds2 are bookmaker odds. return is translation of formula posted by mister Dalvi.

Comment: risultatoPred1 is probability for home team win and risultatoPred2 is probability that away team win.